# Logout MobileFirst invoke procedure' onFailure error details

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Can we just catch the adapter calling failure error details? sample code :

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'UploadAdapter',
    procedure : 'uploadImage',
    parameters : [uuid, base64Str]
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    onSuccess : uploadImageSuccess,
    onFailure : uploadImageFail,
    timeout   : 60000,
});
```

I've already tried this:

```
function uploadImageFail(result){
    WL.Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

But it was just:

```
{"invocationContext":null}
```

My scenario : I'm working on an image uploading adapter (via cordova), and sometimes the uploading may fail. I can easily catch the error message returned from the backend service (which is handled in the `uploadImageSuccess` function), but it's not easy to retrieve the error logs when the invoking procedure goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you need to JSON.stringify it the `result` object. Instead you may want to simply use `result.errorMsg`.

I also googled, and it produced results on the code that needs to be used... so I would try the options provided in the following articles:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/handling_backend_responses_in_adapters?lang=en
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1212_paris/1212_paris.html

Comment: `result.errorMsg` works and which is `Runtime: Http request failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`. Since we encode image into base64 string (which could be quite long), this error occur frequently while calling the uploading adapter.